Cannot see my own router IP in VM machine in Kali Linux
I am trying to scan my own network. I know my router's IP address is other than the one shown to me in Kali Linux in the VM machine. I watched some YouTube videos and asked AI and they say it's because the NAT mode, but I am running all this on a laptop and when I go bridged I loose all connection to the network. I cannot config my own adapter as some videos tell me, but I have options Host-only and LAN segment, but IDK how those work.
Also, I tried netdiscover and it shows all MAC addresses inside the network as VM machines.
What should I do to see the real IP address of my router?
(Sorry, English is my not first language.)

I see you are using a VM such as Virtual Box and have Kali Linux OS installed in that machine and you're having a different IP than your gateway and subnet IP.

First I suggest you use Virtual Box to run and install the VM's OS.
You probably set your VM setting to use NAT, You should chose the option of Bridged just like you described. But you said that's not working. The reason is simple: It's because the bridge settings/or the right interface not enabled.
In the Virtual Box click on the Bridged Adapter option and set the right interface. For example, Intel(R) Wi-Fi-6 you can chose in the dropdown menu several interfaces. Try to figure out the physical one and not the virtual one!
If that's not working you should try different approach. If you're using Windows as your host machine press Win+R key to reveal the RUN and write ncpa.cpl and press OK such as here:

After that detect your existing network connection and click Properties and then add/create network bridge. It could be an option checkbox that you need to check. The name of it is ...Bridge... or something like that.
After that click OK and restart your PC, and then get inside the Virtual Box once again and try to configure the adapter as Bridged Adapter with the Name of the physical interface such as Intel(R) Wi-Fi-6 or something like that. It's something else for each HW interface component. For instance:



Hello, I am the same guy, the adapter option just didn’t appear in my vm machine settings, then I tried with the win+r and when I look for bridged in my properties of my network, there were just no option to add nothing, but somehow I bridged two VMware machines with the WiFi, i guess was the most similar thing I could do, but also didn’t work, thanks, I don’t what other solution u could give me, because there is no information about this in internet that I can found, maybe I did wrong the win+r steps but I search up hard and there is just no option

@cos_trk06 You should give me more details, (1) Just like what adapters are showing you after Name: name me those adapters.
(2) The network is Wifi or Cable?
(3) Are you sure you're pressing properties and Afterwards you seek for Bridge Driver inside the list that appear inside the Networking Tab?
(4) try to check (put V) inside whole of the boxes inside the Networking Tab
(5) are you sure you restarted your PC after?

Thanks , 1) when I go vm machine setting it appears as bridged: connected directly to the physical network, then a box “replicate physical network connection” and I am running this on a laptop. 2) the network is WiFi 3) when I try the command that give and enter into properties of the WiFi, there is no option of adding a bridged driver, there is just checkboxes with programs and install and uninstall options, and in the vm machine when I go the adapter settings it appear programs with checkboxes like bluethodh Microsoft WiFi, nord vpn etc 4) how do I go there? 5) yes,100, thanks for helping me

I already fixed, you helped very much and I really appreciate it, the problem was that my computer was configured with multiple networks because of the default setting in vm machine, I change it only to my main one and, thanks and have a blessed life!

@cos_trk06 you can answer your own question, Maybe with pictures and with detailed explaination, (With a read answer) It could help others, And help you, Try it invest some time in that.
You can show what you had, And how you configured the VM to be, Then and now.
